# PHP Autoload is not called in CLI

Tags: php, shell, namespaces, composer-php, command-line-interface

I have a code that is executing a php script in CLI using shell_exec

because this script is requiring all sort of information that is usually loaded via Apache I have to load them manually.
for example $_REQUIRE and $_SERVER.

This is the command I am executing inside shell_exec

`php -B  "\$_REQUEST =  array('script_path' => 'aaa/bbb.php', 'id' => '55', 'script_params' => '{\"account_id\":\"180000001384\",\"days\":10}'); \$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = '/vvv/www/sss/environment';  require_once('/vvv/www/sss/environment/vendor/autoload.php'); require_once('/vvv/www/sss/environment/services/readerWrapper.php');" > /dev/null 2>/dev/null`

now I get an error that one of my classes is not found.

that class is being loaded using nameSpace:

```
use path/ClassName;
```

my guess is that the autoload.php is not being executed properly.
I also tried requiring directly:
`" require_once('" . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php'); " .`

But it still doesnt work and I get the same error.

what can I do what am I doing wrong ?
thank you!

Edit:
I manage to confirm that the autoload is actually is being called. I can see that it is loading values into the $_GLOBALS array. the problem is that for some reason namespace is not being recognized in the CLI.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: I manage to confirm that the autoload is actually is being called. I can see that it is loading values into the $_GLOBALS array.
the problem is that for some reason namespace is not being recognized in the CLI.
I dont know how to debug it further. not sure why it doesnt work ?

Comment: This is going to be tricky for anyone to help you with without a [mcve]. I imagine the minimum would be a composer.json file with the autoload definition, the entry script (the shortest possible version of readerWrapper.php) and the class defintion that fails to load (with its exact path and file name specified).

Comment: As a side-note, the `-B` switch [is listed as](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) "Run PHP code before processing input lines" but you don't appear to be processing any input lines. You possibly want `-r` instead: "Run PHP code without using script tags". I don't expect it to make any difference here though.